# Does an app's APK have to be downloaded from Google Play to use Google Play services

Tags: google-play, admob, google-play-services, in-app-billing

Looking at the Google Play Services documentation, it doesn't say specifically whether an app has to have been downloaded from Google Play to use Google Play services or InApp purchasing.

Unfortunately virtually all my 200-400 a day free game app downloads are from sites like 'APKMonk' that download apk files directly without using Google Play (and don't ask permission for this). I get maybe 5 or 6 Google Play downloads a day, about 2% of the downloads, as I can't afford spending a load to Google to advertise and getting the download numbers for their top lists is practically impossible for independent developers otherwise.

Google Analytics and Admob serves have been working with these rogue downloads, but I'm getting no InApp purchases, even for free promo items, and very few leaderboard and achievement posts (12 leaderboard posts out of thousands of rogue downloads so far).

Is this because they didn't download from Google Play in the first place? Should I add a message to uninstall their apps and reinstall from Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where they have been downloaded from.

For inApp purchases, it only matters whether they have Google play installed on their device.